# Is it possible to rename an Intent in Amazon Lex?

Tags: amazon-lex

I am using Amazon Lex to build a chatbot. I have an intent called `GetPersonalLoan` which I now want to break down into multiple intents like `GetPersonalDetails`, `GetLoanDetails` and so on. So is there any option to change the name of the intent `GetPersonalLoan`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no ability to rename intents. You can copy or move intents to other lex bots, but the name is fixed and cannot be used a second time in your AWS account. You will have to create a new intent for the new name.

Comment: For more information, you can't even change a letter to uppercase/lowercase. It regards 'getPersonalLoan' and 'GetPersonalLoan' as the same intent.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/migration.html
Renaming resources

> With Amazon Lex V2 you can rename a resource after it's created. Use a
> resource name to associate user-friendly metadata with each resource.
> The Amazon Lex V2 API assigns every resource a unique 10-character
> resource ID. All resources have a resource name. You can rename the
> following resources:
>
> Bot
>
> Intent
>
> Slot type
>
> Slot
>
> Alias