# Is it possible to rename a Bot in Amazon Lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I created a bot in Amazon Lex, i would like to know if there's a way to rename it ? or i have to delete it and create a new one ?

Answer (score 2):

### No

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The developer is not able to rename any existing Bots or [Intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556113/is-it-possible-to-rename-an-intent-in-amazon-lex). Your best bet is probably to delete and create a new bot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is not possible in LEX we can only edit the slot names in Lex.